# How to control the x-axis in ms chart control time-wise?

Tags: c#, timer, mschart

I'm reading data from serial port and displaying it in ms-chart control. I just don't know to  have in my chart area just 5 vertical bars in total (1 second apart) -> a total of 5 seconds data in my chart area and have the no. of seconds displayed on the X axis.

```
`       timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        timer.Interval = 100;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 1024;
        chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;



        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string data;
            data = _port.ReadExisting();

            var dataBlocks = data.Split('\n');

           foreach (var block in dataBlocks)
            {
              var numbers = block.Split(new [] {' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
              for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
              {
                double n = double.NaN;
                bool ok = double.TryParse(numbers[i], out n);
                if (ok)
                {
                    if (n > 30)
                    {
                        chart1.Series[i].Points.AddXY(x, n);
                        if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 700)
                            chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);
                    }
                }               
                }
             }       
            }`
```

[image]

Comment: An image often helps a lot when desribing chart issues.

Comment: image added....

Comment: Ok, that looks like what one would expect from the code. But what is it you want different? Other Label values? Less points? What 'vertical bars' are you talking about? The Major Gridlines?? And what about '5 seconds'?? You collect 700  points froma 100ms timer. I'm confused.

Comment: Ideally I would like to have a graph showing the cardiac activity over 5 seconds,with a Gridline displayed every second => 5 gridlines in total. I would also like to have for each gridline on the Xaxis  the current second written.

Comment: Ah, ok. What is the `x` you feed in as the XValue? Does it contain a datetime?

Comment: Currently  int x = 0; when I start the code. I don't change it afterwards. I tried to use a datetime to somehow keep track of time elapsed but it didn't work out. I was able however to get rid of the major grid on x-axis easily. So, I did some advancement...

Comment: _I was able however to get rid of the major grid_ lol, that is simple indeed. But how could the seconds be displayed if you do not feed in any kind of time values?? And keeping it at 0, (which you do not do looking at the image btw) is of course nonsene. Don't the data come in with a timestamp? If they don't, what use are they anyway?? I wold expect that info to be as impertant as the y-values. If you need to you can always feed in DateTime.Now.. Then you can format the labels to "ss" and pick an Interval that shows only one line per second..

Comment: Thing is, if I do put a DateTime instead of that x, it doesn't show me anything anymore. I did recheck my code I do not operate on x at all. In short, I don't understand either why it works. Data do come with a timestamp -> The serial port is open and using the timer (which is set to 500ms now) I take the data and put it on the chart.....every 500ms...

Comment: I guess, the timing goes with the sliding effect that you should me in another thread (removing the 1st value from the chart)...... But I'm stucked :(

Comment: Once you add the x-values as DateTimes you also should and can set up the other properirte: `Axis ax = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX; ax.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
ax.Interval = 1000;
s.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;ax.LabelStyle.Format = "ss";` - After removing the the first DataPoints you may or may not want to set the min/max values: `ax.Minimum =  s.Points.First().XValue;
                ax.Maximum =  s.Points.Last().XValue;`..

Comment: for `ax.Interval` you should use a value that actually calculates to one line per second. So if you add 200 points per second set it to 200 etc..

Comment: Thanks so far. This is what I do now:  chart1.Series[i].Points.AddXY(DateTime.Now.Millisecond, n);
Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;  ax.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds;
 ax.Interval = 1000;
 chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
 ax.LabelStyle.Format = "ss"; if (chart1.Series[0].Points.Count > 1000)
                            chart1.Series[0].Points.RemoveAt(0);   What I get is total nonsense:  straight lines that originate on Y axis ! :(

Comment: _AddXY(DateTime.Now.Millisecond_ do give it the full data: `AddXY(DateTime.Now,..)` but if you can use the real data the results will be a lot more meaningful:  I think you are unpacking at whole bundle of data every 1/2 second? If you then quickly add them with DataTime.Now, all get the same x-value. The original data should be used..

Comment: Still not able to solve it. I noticed that at every time_tick (500ms in my case), the number of values I get from the serial port is NOT the same (sometimes 600, sometimes 1000). It varies greatly. The baudrate is 57600 (data come from the aquisition board).  Also, I did check and that value x (for AddXY) does not change at all, during the whole course. :(

Comment: Well, in that case you would have to calculate an avarage delta for the x-values. you know the actual time, either because you know the timer intervall (500ms) or beause you can get it from datetime.now. and you know the number of data point you have received. So you divide the time delta by that number and use it to count up estimated x-values..

Comment: I got this: int counter = 0; double delta = (double) dataBlocks.Length /(double)500; and when I add the points: chart1.Series[i].Points.AddXY(counter * delta, n); counter++; It doesn't work but it shows some horizontal lines and I dont have the "moving" effect anymore :(

Comment: hm, what does the debugger show for the x-values??

Comment: 0.878, 1.748, 2.622, 3.496, 4.37, 5.244,6.188 where the batch size of values from the port = 437 (1st batch), delta = batch_size / 500 = 0.874 . Code: double temp = counter * delta; chart1.Series[i].Points.AddXY(temp, n); counter++; Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX; ax.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Milliseconds; ax.Interval = 500; chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime; ax.LabelStyle.Format = "ss"; Each time a new batch arrives from port, i reset the counter to 0. And all that i get on the chart "agglutinates" in the 1st  tenth of the X-axis.